# Boolean 'not' operator not working correctly

Tags: python, boolean

I managed to fix my code except that I can't figure out how to make the boolean part work. We are supposed to use the `not` operator, but I am not quite sure what is the right way to use it:

```
def copy_me(list_input):
    ''' (list) -> list
    A function takes as input a list, and returns a copy 
    of the list with the following changes:
    Strings have all their letters converted to upper-case
    Integers and floats have their value increased by 1
    booleans are negated (False becomes True, True becomes False)
    Lists are replaced with the word ”List”
    The function should leave the original input list unchanged

    >>> copy_me(["aa", 5, ["well", 4], True)
    ['AA', 6, 'List', False]
    >>> copy_me([20932498, 4], 5.98, "And", False)
    ['List', 6.98, 'AND', True]
    '''

    # if element is a string, change all the letters to upper case
    # if element is an integer or float, have their value increased by 1
    # if element is a boolean, negate it
    # if element is a list, replace it with the word "List"


    new_list = list_input[:]

    for index in range(len(new_list)):
        if isinstance(new_list[index], str):
            new_list[index].upper()
        elif isinstance(new_list[index], int):
            new_list[index] += 1
        elif isinstance(new_list[index], float):
            new_list[index] += 1.0
        elif isinstance(new_list[index], list):
            new_list[index] = "List"
        elif isinstance(new_list[index], bool):
            not new_list[index]

    return new_list
```

Comment: where's the assignment?

Answer (score 2):

`not new_list[index]` is an expression with no side effects meaning that it is essentially a no op.

You probably mean the following instead:

```
new_list[index] = not new_list[index]
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to actually reassign the value of `new_list[index]` in these two places:

```
if isinstance(new_list[index], str):
    new_list[index] = new_list[index].upper()
...
elif isinstance(new_list[index], bool):
    new_list[index] = not new_list[index]
```

Without the `=` assignment, the value remains unchanged because neither `str.upper` nor the `not` operator work in-place.

Answer (score 0):

You just forgot to assign the negation to `new_list[index]`

Another trick, with booleans:

```
new_list[index] = (new_list[index] == True)
```

It returns `True` if `True` else `False`.

But this is not what you need here. Just the assignment was missing as I said.

Comment: Why would you use that over just `not new_list[index]`? In some circumstances, they can even do different things... :)

Comment: Agreed, I clarified my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is hat you need:

```
for index in range(len(new_list)):
    if isinstance(new_list[index], str):
        new_list[index].upper()
    elif isinstance(new_list[index], int):
        new_list[index] += 1
    elif isinstance(new_list[index], float):
        new_list[index] += 1.0
    elif isinstance(new_list[index], list):
        new_list[index] = "List"
    elif isinstance(new_list[index], bool):
        if new_list[index]:
            new_list[index]=False
        else:new_list[index]=True
```